How to Dynamically loading remote components using their selectors through native federation in angular?
I have a micro frontend (products repo) running on port 4202. The federation configuration for this repo (federation.config.js) is as follows:
const { withNativeFederation, shareAll } = require('@angular-architects/native-federation/config');

module.exports = withNativeFederation({
  name: 'mfe2',
  exposes: {
    './SelectorLoaded': './src/app/selector-loaded/selector-loaded.component.ts',
    // other exposed components
  },
  // additional configuration
});

I want to dynamically load the SelectorLoaded component from mfe2 and use its selector directly inside a parent component in the host application. I also want to send inputs and receive outputs from the SelectorLoaded component seamlessly.
To achieve this, I implemented the following method:
loadMicroFrontend3() {
  loadRemoteModule('mfe2', './SelectorLoaded')
    .then((MicroModule: any) => {
      const ce = createCustomElement(MicroModule.SelectorLoadedComponent, {
        injector: this.injector,
      });

      if (!customElements.get('app-selector-loaded')) {
        customElements.define('app-selector-loaded', ce);
      }
    })
    .catch((err: any) => console.error('Error loading microfrontend:', err));
}

However, this approach does not work. Even though I can successfully load and render the SelectorLoaded component using a route configuration like this:
{
  path: 'stepper',
  loadComponent: () =>
    loadRemoteModule('mfe2', './SelectorLoaded').then((m) => m.SelectorLoadedComponent),
}

// federation.manifest.json
{
  "mfe1": "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.json",
  "mfe2": "http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.json"
}

I cannot use the SelectorLoadedComponent as a selector (e.g., <app-selector-loaded></app-selector-loaded>) within a host component in the shell app.
I was able to achieve this behavior with Module Federation, but it doesn't seem to work with Native Federation.
My Questions:

Is there a way to dynamically load and use an exposed micro frontend component with Native Federation so that I can:

Use its selector directly within the host app?
Pass inputs and listen for outputs as if it were a local Angular component?


If not, what is the recommended way to achieve this functionality with Native Federation?

